# Good way to collapse certain Table/ cells when using ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular

This is a Angular project v7 or so! im including angular tag because i dont know if there is any angular helpers for this.

I have multiple tables based on NG for, for each table i have a collapse/expand button. i want the individual table (button clicked) to collapse the table, my current solution isnt working properly because im using one bool and if you click expand/collapse on another table the boolean is incorrect for the others.

Im new to this, so i may of greatly over complicated the attmepted solution. :)

added a class to collapsable panels, then loop through elemens to add/remove classes based on bool.

```
viewDetailOption(event) {
    console.log(this.show)
    this.show = !this.show;
    console.log(this.show)
    // Toggle the Arrows
    event.srcElement.classList.toggle('fa-angle-double-right');
    event.srcElement.classList.toggle('fa-angle-double-left');

    const parentNode = event.srcElement.parentNode.parentNode;
    const childNodes = parentNode.querySelectorAll('.extendedViewOnly')
    if (this.show) {
        for (let i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
            childNodes[i].classList.remove('extendedViewOnly');
            // show is not used in CSS, is added to identify when a hidden field is shown
            childNodes[i].classList.add('show');
        }
    } else {
        const hiddenNodes = parentNode.querySelectorAll('.show')
        for (let i = 0; i < hiddenNodes.length; i++) {
            hiddenNodes[i].classList.remove('show');
            hiddenNodes[i].classList.add('extendedViewOnly');
        }
    }
}
```

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <app-tab-selector [contactDescription]='contactDescription' [contactId]="id" [data]="contactDetails"></app-tab-selector>
  <br>
  <a class="btn btn-raised btn-primary">Add</a>
  <section id="striped-light">
    <div class="row text-left">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="card" *ngFor="let contact of contactDetails; let i = index" [attr.id]="'fcard' + i">
          <div class="card-header">
            <p class="card-title">{{contact.name}} </p>
            <span class="pull-right fa fa-2x fa-angle-double-right" (click)="viewDetailOption($event)" placement="top" ngbTooltip="Collapse / Expand"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <div class="card-body">
              <table class="table table-striped ">
                <thead>
                  <tr [attr.id]="'fr' + i">
                    <th> No.</th>
                    <th>Capacity</th>
                    <th>T/A</th>
                    <th>SType</th>
                    <th>SLayout</th>
                    <th class="extendedViewOnly">RS</th>
                    <th class="extendedViewOnly">TA</th>
                    <th class="extendedViewOnly">SA</th>
                    <th class="extendedViewOnly">DR</th>
                    <th class="extendedViewOnly">FE</th>
                    <th class="extendedViewOnly">NB</th>
                    <th class="extendedViewOnly">LT</th>
                    <th class="">Operations</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody >
                  <tr *ngFor="let item of contact.ph">
                    <td>{{item2.no}}</td>
                    <td>{{item2.cap}}</td>
                    <td>{{item2.ta}}</td>
                    <td>{{item2.st}}</td>
                    <td>{{item2.}}</td>
                    <td class="extendedViewOnly">{{item2.}}</td>
                    <td class="extendedViewOnly">{{item2.}}</td>
                    <td class="extendedViewOnly">{{item2.}}</td>
                    <td class="extendedViewOnly">1200m</td>
                    <td class="extendedViewOnly">{{item2.}}</td>
                    <td class="extendedViewOnly">{{item2.}}</td>
                    <td class="extendedViewOnly">{{item2.}}</td>
                    <td class="extendedViewOnly">{{item2.}}</td>
                    <td class="extendedViewOnly">{{item2.}}</td>
                    <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-2x"></i></a></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

To be able to expand and collapse multiple tables, a state for each, is there a way to do this properly or maybe array of states?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If this is an Angular project, could you please add the template you're referencing?

Comment: Many thanks Jens, Dont be too harsh ;) - Note I removed some names of fields just because of internal data. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a boolean property `displayInfo` to your `contact`, and toggle this instead of trying to manage the HTML inside the JavaScript. With this property set, you can use ngClass to assign the correct class (double-right, double-left, show)...

It is always better to leave the HTML handling for Angular, and only care about the object states.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I see is that you have a collection of items and you are using a single boolean to hide or display those items.

So what you can do is to store the ID of the items you want to display in a hashtable.

The solution may be like this:

The template:

```html
...

<div class="card" *ngFor="let contact of contactDetails; let i = index" [attr.id]="'fcard' + i">
              <div class="card-header">
                <p class="card-title">{{contact.name}} </p>
                <span class="pull-right fa fa-2x fa-angle-double-right" (click)="viewDetailOption($event, contact)" placement="top" ngbTooltip="Collapse / Expand"></span> </div>

...
```

The TS file:

```js
// conmponent class
itemsToShow = {};


viewDetailOption(event, contact) {
    console.log(this.itemsToShow[constact.id])
    this.itemsToShow[constact.id] = !this.itemsToShow[constact.id];

    // ... the rest of your logic here
}
```

Comment: I must say though that accessing elements trough the event or the querySelector to add style classes is a bad habit and could be seen as a code smell. A better way to do it is by using the ngCless directive. read more about it [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)